# Seeking critique on website design

Tags: website-design

I'm looking for some constructive feedback on a website I've just designed. I'm curious your thoughts on the:

- Typography (Is the font readable for you? Is there enough contrast?)
- Color selection (There's a very subtle gradient on the background of the header. Is this even noticeable?)
- Logo (I used an SVG, which I've been very impressed with versus using a static image. I wanted to stray away from using just text so I tried to incorporate an image into the logo.)
- The animations (do you like them?)

It's a very simple single page website. You can view it [here](https://www.drinkdesmoines.com/). Thanks!

Comment: There's a webite intended for these types of questions: https://usability.testing.exchange — you give feedback to others about their work, and then you get back answers to your questions, about as much text, as you gave as feedback to others. Feel free to go there and post your question and link to your site. (I'm developing UTX.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typography: looks fine, non-offensive so great.

Color selection: once you pointed it out I see the gradient. This might not be the best blue to use.

Logo: Drink with a beer? It's fine but unremarkable. What's not static about it?

The animations: the product logos resizing? Not a problem.

All in all there is an amazing lack of things to criticize. The main page is very plain and boring and empty. It doesn't clearly explain the purpose(this is a sign up for a newsletter that shows drink deals).

The only visually interesting things are the venue logos at the bottom, and its not clear that they are an entrance into another section.

I am proud of my work when I can make it look like a template. It means I've successfully created a commercial look. You are in danger of looking too much like a template.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. What specifically don't you like about the blue? Just personal preference or some other reason. By static, I meant that it's not a png (using an svg).

Comment: And I do agree, there isn't a lot of content here yet. It's just in the beginning stages. However, I can see why you would think it looks like a template. There isn't anything so far that really stands out. I think I'll need to brainstorm some ways to add some flair.

Comment: It's hard to define what I don't like about the blue. It's too saturated, too close to 100% C, which looks like old link blue, so old fashioned. At the sides where the gradient is darker it is in danger of appearing purple (try to get a 30% difference between red and blue to avoid purple). I think it should be darker, less blue in your blue.